# How can I manage the state of my application using a dedicated object instead of what React offers?

Tags: javascript, web-development, react

Most of the react application I've seen are organized with components that, in my opinion, do too much.

They may follow this pattern:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = this.props.prop1;
        this.prop2 = this.props.prop2;
    }

    render() {
        //....
    }

    onEvent(e) {
        this.setState({
            prop1: getProp1(),
            prop2: this.prop2() 
        });
    }
}
```

Personally in most cases I would prefer to avoid managing the state through React, and to have an object that does this. A possible solution would be something similar to:

```
class MyState {

    update(params) {
        this.prop1 = getProp1();
    }

}


class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state.obj = this.props.obj; // this has type MyState
    }

    render() {
        //....
    }

    onEvent(e) {
        this.obj.update(e.something);
        this.setState(this.obj);
    }
}
```

Since I've never seen this pattern used, and I'm not sure if using the same object as a prop and for the state, I wondering if I am missing something here.

Is this idea bad for some reason? Is there a better solution to manage the component state (as a whole, or just a subset) in a dedicated object?

Comment: Sounds like you want MobX.

Comment: I know that redux and mobX offer alternative solution to the state problem, and I know that when the app complexity grows they become almost a necessity, but I still feel that in some smaller applications a simple state-managing pattern may be a better solution.

Comment: I would agree if one was built into React, but I think you may be better off going with a known solution like MobX. It's actually pretty simple once you get the hang of it, and not too far from what you're trying to do.